# Problem calling a method from visualforce

Tags: apex

I want the User Id to be displayed in a visualforce page

```
 public class getUser{

   public void classGetID()
   {
     String s=UserInfo.getUserId();
   }
 }
```

Following is my visualforce page..

```
 <apex:page Controller="getUser" >

    <apex:outputText value="!classGetID"></apex:outputText>

 </apex:page>
```

Please guide me how do get the user ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You need to return the Id in your method (your method is void which means it won't return anything if you call it) - like this:

```
public Id classGetId()
{
    return Userinfo.getUserId();
}
```

Then in your page you need to call this method (your syntax is not correct) like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!classGetID}"></apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the User global variable, which would be quite straight forward

```
 <apex:outputText value=" {!$User.Id}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I was learning to call methods into visualforce.

Comment: Then @Bachovski's answer would fit in.

Comment: Nice catch @codebandit!